# LINQ query operator for log table

Tags: linq

I am trying to find the corerct LINQ to SQL query operator and predicate combo that can operate on an audit table.

Imagine a table called Setting that has three columns : rowID, DefID, and Value.

I want to be able to check that every DefID ( in this case all definition 1 through 3 ) has at least one row which has a value set to true.

the LINQ expression should return a bool true or false.  For example,

```
RowID    DefID    Value
1        1        true
2        2        false
3        3        true
```

LINQ returns false because DefID = 2 does not have any value = true

```
RowID    DefID    Value
1        1        true
2        2        false
3        2        true
```

returns false because defid 3 is missing

```
RowID    DefID    Value
1        1        true
2        1        false
3        2        true
4        3        true
```

returns true because ALL definitions have at least one value = true

Comment: You need to be slightly more specific. How do you know to stop at DefID = 3 in your second example, for instance? Isn't DefID = 4 "missing" from your third example?

Comment: I know that there are exactly 3 definitions; 1, 2 and 3.  So I have the full set of definition IDs I am looking for. Any array of ints like [1,2,3] is available.

Comment: Do you already have the linq query to produce the above output and are looking for something to add to it to return true/false? Or are you asking for the whole thing?

Comment: I am just looking for the true false... I have the "Select" query reproducing the simplified version above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using extension methods:

```
int[] ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

bool allFound = Settings.Where( s => s.Value && ids.Contains( s.DefID ) )
                        .Select( s => s.DefID )
                        .Distinct()
                        .Count() == ids.Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used linq to sql, but the linq to objects would look something like this:

```
defIds.All(d => d.rows.Any( row => row.Value == true ) )
```

To do it in raw SQL, I don't think it's possible in one query. You could do something like this though:

```
select id from DefIds
join rows on row.DefId = DefIds.ID
where row.Value = true
```

That would give you a list of defId's which have true values. In code you could then do something like

```
DefIds.Select(d => d.id).ToArray() == (results from select).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a lot of valid ways to do this.  One simple way is:

```
int[] DefIDs = new int[] {1, 2, 3};

bool bHasValidDefs =
    (
    from set in myDataBase.settings
    where 
        set.Value == true
        && DefIDs.Contains(set.DefID)
    select set.DefID
    ).Distinct().Count() == DefIDs.Count();
```

This gets the number of unique DefIDs that are in your valid list and also have at least one "value == true" row.  It then makes sure that the number of these valid DefIDs is equal to the expected value that you define above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with having a ValidSettings or SettingsMaster table, you could:

```
bool allFound = myContext.SettingsMaster.All(m=> m.Settings.Any(s=>s.Value));
```

For the current tables version, I would

```
int[] allIds = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
var validIds = (
    from s in myContext.Settings 
    where s.Value 
    select s.DefId
    )
    .Distinct().ToList();
bool allFound = allIds.All(id => validIds.Contains(id));
```